# Is it possible to construct a datadog graph with a metric that matches two values for one tag?

Tags: datadog

I *think* this should be possible, but I can't find documented syntax. I would like to construct a DD graph that displays metrics matching tag_one:A or tag_one:B. Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the following should work:

tag_one:(A OR B)

Unfortunately the query syntax is slightly different in different contexts, I find, so I don't know if that will solve your particular problem.